# MongoDB on Docker (sharding) Connection failed

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, sharding, compass

I can't connect to my MongoDb router.
This is my docker-compose:

```
    version: '3.5'
    
    volumes:
        mongoshard1_volume:
        mongoshard2_volume:
        mongoconf_volume:
    
    services:
        # MONGO DB SERVICES
        # Node storing the first shard mongoshard1:
            container_name: mongoshard1
            image: mongo
            command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet "mongors1" --dbpath /data/db --port ${MONGO_SHARD_PORT:-27017}
            restart: on-failure
            expose:
                - "${MONGO_SHARD_PORT:-27017}"
            environment:
                TERM: bash
                TZ: ${TIMEZONE}
            volumes:
                - mongoshard1_volume:/data/db
            entrypoint:
                - docker-entrypoint.sh
    
        # Node storing the second shard mongoshard2:
            container_name: mongoshard2
            image: mongo
            command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet "mongors2" --dbpath /data/db --port ${MONGO_SHARD_PORT:-27017}
            restart: on-failure
            expose:
                - "${MONGO_SHARD_PORT:-27017}"
            environment:
                TERM: bash
                TZ: ${TIMEZONE}
            volumes:
                - mongoshard2_volume:/data/db
    
        # Node storing the configuration for the cluster mongoconf:
            container_name: mongoconf
            depends_on: 
                - mongoshard1
                - mongoshard2
            image: mongo
            command: mongod --configsvr --replSet "mongorsconf" --dbpath /data/db --port ${MONGO_CONFIG_PORT:-27017}
            restart: on-failure
            expose: 
                - "${MONGO_CONFIG_PORT:-27017}"
            environment:
                TERM: bash
                TZ: ${TIMEZONE}
            volumes: 
                - mongoconf_volume:/data/db
    
        # Node acting as the router for the mongorouter:
            container_name: mongorouter
            depends_on:
                - mongoconf
            image: mongo
            command: mongos --configdb mongorsconf/mongoconf:${MONGO_CONFIG_PORT:-27017} --port ${MONGO_ROUTER_PORT:-27017} --bind_ip_all
            restart: on-failure
            expose:
                - "${MONGO_ROUTER_PORT:-27017}"
            ports:
                - ${MONGO_ROUTER_PORT:-27017}:${MONGO_ROUTER_PORT:-27017}
            environment:
                TERM: bash
                TZ: ${TIMEZONE}
```

and this is my setup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose up -d
seconds=3

echo "Executing needed commands on MongoConf, MongoShard1, MongoShard2"
sleep $seconds

cmd="echo 'rs.initiate({_id: "mongorsconf", configsvr: true, members: [{ _id : 0, host : "mongoconf" }]})' | mongo"
docker exec -it mongoconf bash -c $cmd

cmd="echo 'rs.initiate({_id : "mongors1", members: [{ _id : 0, host : "mongoshard1" }]})' | mongo"
docker exec -it mongoshard1 bash -c  $cmd

cmd="echo 'rs.initiate({_id : "mongors2", members: [{ _id : 0, host : "mongoshard2" }]})' | mongo"
docker exec -it mongoshard2 bash -c  $cmd

echo "Done"

echo "Adding shards to MongoRouter"
sleep $seconds

cmd="echo 'sh.addShard("mongors1/mongoshard1")' | mongo"
docker exec -it mongorouter bash -c $cmd

cmd="echo 'sh.addShard("mongors2/mongoshard2")' | mongo"
docker exec -it mongorouter bash -c $cmd
```

When I try to connect to my MongoDB router, I receive a connection error. I tried to connect through MongoDBCompass using localhost:27017 and using MongoClient on Python too. All the server are "running" on Docker. I can't a solution for this problem, I lost like two days over it.

After the comment, I leave also this part of the code (I think is not important):

```
# MariaDB container
    mariadb:
        container_name: mariadb
        image: mariadb
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASS:-rootpass}
        ports:
            - ${MARIADB_PORT:-3306}:${MARIADB_PORT:-3306}
        volumes:
            - mariadb_volume:/var/lib/mysql

    # MISCELLANEOUS SERVICES
    # Adminer (phpMyAdmin alternative) container
    adminer:
        container_name: adminer
        image: adminer
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mariadb
            ADMINER_DESIGN: galkaev
        ports:
            - ${ADMINER_PORT:-8080}:${ADMINER_PORT:-8080}
```

Comment: The docker-compose.yml is a nested key-value structure. Yours has multiple values with the same key at the same level, which can't work.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Can you point out the correct syntax to create such a list of services?

Comment: [edit] your question to complete it. For YAML, the formatting as an important part and the comments here can't express that. Also, people shouldn't have to search for bits of info in the comments.

Comment: I edit, sorry I'm new